# Casting between shared_ptr of forward declared class hierarchy

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a class manipulating only shared_ptr to an inheritance hierarchy (quite simple, there are a few classes, say `A, B, C` etc. inheriting from a single class `Base`). Since I do not need to manipulate the instances of A, B, C... themselves, they are only forward declared. However, the compiler chokes when I try to pass a `shared_ptr<A>` to a method taking a `shared_ptr<Base>`, since the compiler does not know that A inherits from Base. Is there any other way than either `static_pointer_cast`or `#include`the header of class A? And if not, which one would you choose?

EDIT: adding some code

```
// in some file: (Base.h)
class Base
{
    /*code*/
}

// in another file (A.h)
class A : public Base
{
}

// in my file (impl.cpp)
class A; // forward declaration    

void Dummy()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> myPtr;

    // we have somewhere: void sillyFunction(shared_ptr<Base> foo)
    sillyFunction(myPtr); // does not compile, as no conversion is found.
}
```

Comment: An code example would demonstrate your problem better than in words.

Comment: Separate the implementation from the declarations and provide the implementation with the full declarations of the derived classes. This should work. Post more details if you're still having problems.

Comment: The declaration is separate from the implementation. The thing is, I seem to have only a name dependency and I don't really want to have a full dependency on the classes A, B, C...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other way than either static_pointer_castor #includethe header of class A?

No. In fact, the `#include` is the only way to do it properly (`static_pointer_cast` either wouldn't work or invokes undefined behavior). You can't cast ordinary pointers between incomplete subclass and superclass, either.